# How to export asp.net page to MS Word with header, footer

Tags: asp.net, export-to-word

document table in SQL server database is :

```
id
title
content
first_name
last_name
department
logo
```

How can i export to word with template like image below.

[image: word file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use OpenXML SDK to achieve what you are looking for. 
DocX API - docx.codeplex.com. is a really good and easy alternative to Open XML SDK.

Comment: Hi Flowering, it work well but the content of .doc had HTML tag, for exmaple : <p><em><strong> Hasdasdf asfd asfa sdft</strong></em></p>. How can i fix it?

Comment: @Hainlp Sorry but I didn't get you, Are you trying to convert HTML to DOC, but the API is to be used in C# programatically to generate a Word Document directly..

Comment: Thanks Flowerking. I will search more :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template word document with content controls as placeholders for dynamic data, and then use the OpenXML SDK to insert data in the content controls.

Comment: Thanks granaker, can you explain more detail. I'm a beginer

Answer (score 0):

You could try using http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx either with MailMerge or create the document from scratch.